# How to get a O(n log k)-time comparison-based algorithm to sort k-multiset?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

if I have an array {1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5} this is a sorted 5-multiset of size n= 12, and k = 5 (distinct keys). What is a O(n log k)-time comparison-based  algorithm to sort k-multiset for a similar unsorted array?
The approach I had in mind is 3-way partition quick sort.

Comment: Think [counting sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm) and why having a limit on the number of `distinct keys` might be needed/useful.

Comment: I didn't say *do* counting sort: I wrote (and meant) *think* and find out *why*.

Answer (score 1):

Just inserting the elements into a balanced binary search tree yields the required complexity. Each node of the tree may store the value and the count of such values in the input so far, as in counting sort. The tree will have size at most `k`, and the number of insertions will be `n`, hence `O(n log k)` total time. The binary search tree is comparison-based, so the requirement is satisfied.

If it is somehow completely forbidden to use counts, we may store linked lists of equal values in each node of the tree, if only to ridicule the requirement.

Comment: What do u think about the method I proposed? As 3 way quick sort will have T(n) = 3T(k/3)+n . Where its worst case will be when they are all distinct elements giving nlgn same as the BST. The reason I proposed this is to make sure to by pass the possibility of count sort beig forbidden

Comment: @amroto I don't see how it's `T(n) = 3T(k/3) + n`, can you please elaborate? This does not make sense for me, as there are two parameters (`n` and `k`), and the left part does not mention `k`. As I see it, the worst case for three-way partition quicksort will still be `O(nk)`, when we have an array `[1, 2, ..., k-2, k-1, k, k, k, ..., k, k]`, and the pivots happen to be `1`, `2`, ..., `k-2`, `k-1`, `k`, in that order.

Comment: correct me if I am incorrect. So, I have k distinct keys. assume picking any number as a pivot, this will divide ur array to 3 parts, on the first pass all elements of that pivot are now sorted and no longer need to check them again. This means that each time I will pass on the array each time. While the size of the array is n and is divided to smaller pieces. Truely the worest average case, when all the keys are distinct O(nlgn). and worst worst case when I have the array dividing only in 2 parts and creating 2 sub arrays of 1 and n-1, when the largest/smallest element is chosen each time.

Comment: making it O(n^2)

Comment: @amroto Yeah, it makes sense for me now. I agree that the average case of three-way quicksort is `T(n,k) = n log k`. Here, the `n` factor is from the partitioning pass, and `log k` is the average depth of recursion. Indeed, quicksort being three-way allows us to consider all equal elements as a single one when arguing about recursion depth.